# Remove Delete product functionality for a specific user role

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, user-roles

How to remove delete product functionality for a specific user role? ( The user should only have access to edit the products. ) In default magento community edition i cannot achieve this. Which code should i modify to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom module. Make the necessary name changes and add this to the etc/config.xml. Rewriting adminthtml to remove the delete and mass delete. Events are to lock a particular attribute if you don't want to give the user role to edit that attribute.

```
             <blocks>
                        <custom_catalog>
                            <class>Custom_Catalog_Block</class>
                        </custom_catalog>
                        <adminhtml>
                            <rewrite>
                                 <catalog_product_edit>Custom_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Edit</catalog_product_edit>
                                 <catalog_product_grid>Custom_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                            </rewrite>
                        </adminhtml>
           </blocks>
           <events>
                <catalog_product_edit_action>
                <observers>
                    <custom_catalog>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>custom_catalog/observer</class>
                        <method>lockAttributes</method>
                    </custom_catalog>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_edit_action>
            <catalog_product_new_action>
                <observers>
                    <custom_catalog>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>custom_catalog/observer</class>
                        <method>lockAttributes</method>
                    </custom_catalog>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_new_action>    
            </events>
```

Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php (This is to remove the delete button in the product edit page)

```
class Custom_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit
{
 public function getDeleteButtonHtml()
    {
        $currentUser = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        $currentRole = $currentUser->getRole();
        $roleId = $currentRole->getId();
        //hardcoded the user role id for demo purposes
        if($roleId == 1){
            return $this->getChildHtml('delete_button');
        }else{
             return '';
        }

    }
}
```

Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php (This is to remove the mass delete from actions in all products page)

```
class Custom_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();
         $currentUser = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        $currentRole = $currentUser->getRole();
        $roleId = $currentRole->getId();
        //hardcoded the user role id for demo purposes
        if($roleId != 1){
            //like this you can remove other actions as well. eg:- status
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('delete');               
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Model/Observer.php (To lock attributes in product edit page if required)

```
class Custom_Catalog_Model_Observer {

    public function lockAttributes($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $currentUser = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        $currentRole = $currentUser->getRole();
        $roleId = $currentRole->getId();
        //hardcoded the user role id for demo purposes
        if($roleId != 1){
            //like this you can lock any attribute you like in product edit
            $product->lockAttribute('price');
            $product->lockAttribute('status');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but nothing happens user still have the DELETE button

Comment: `//hardcoded the user role id for demo purposes
if($roleId != 1){
            //like this you can remove other actions as well. eg:- status
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('delete');               
        }`
You need to change the roleid according to the user role that you want to hide it.

Comment: i created a new user whose id is 2, and i changed in Edit.php